# Issue with mvn compile for executable files

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am facing a weird issue, I have added an executable file (mod 777) in my project directory.

When I run `mvn compile`, the converted class file that is copied in `classes` directory, inside `target` directory, is somehow removing the executable mode and converted it to non executable file, due to which it throws an error, `IllegalStateException : The file isn't executable`.

```
mvn compile
```

Any idea why the executable file is converted to a non executable file, what needs to be done here, I am not getting any clue.

Comment: What do you mean by ` executable file (mod 777) in my project directory`? Why do you need an executable file within a Java project?

Comment: I am running a selenium project which needs an executable webdriver to be present in the project (like chromeDriver) which gets launched for the command being executed.

Comment: I would suggest to use something like this: https://github.com/webdriverextensions/webdriverextensions-maven-plugin

Comment: yep that can be done, but I wanted to understand why the property of file is being changed during compile time.